# Trying do determine how to rank water flow measurements?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, ranking, t-distribution

I'm doing a study that involves waterflow measurements as it relates to erosion prioritizing.  I'd like to rank between (0-1) a population of 160 values with a minimum of 2.1 and a maximum of 5.9  The mean is 4.1 and the standard deviation is .69.  The frequency distribution resembles a bell curve and the readings are from areas with similarities.  what are some ways to go about this? Do I need to have another parameter to correlate to?

Thanks,

Jessi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the following transformation to your sample of observations $X$:
$$ Z = \frac{X - \min(X)}{\max(X) - \min(X)}$$

$Z$ is defined between $[0,1]$.